# Transferwise refund

Tags: refund

Wise asked me to send documents regarding EU regulation. I sent them documents two times and they verified it. Yesterday I wanted to send 250 Euro to my account in wise from my account in santander bank. I sent money and I see that the money received but paused receiving in wise. Again it was written that the account is blocked. Complete verification. Due to the fact that my documents are in embassy I could not do it in this time. I sent an email to them they said that "we wont hold money for too long" and if "we did not get any response for 2 working days we refund the money". Anyway, I cancelled the transfer. The issue is I saw my money in wise as cancelled but when I look updates it is still written complete verification. So, this means that I even need to verify if I want to get money back?!! However, the money is not actually deposit to my wise account but paused. Again I email them and they said that the money will be turned back to your account within 1 to 3 working days.

So for those with same experience or at least same experience, do they refund money? Also, since it is new year times, what does it mean by 1-3 working days?

Answer (score 2):

"Working days' generally means weekdays (Monday through Friday) when the business is not closed for some reason. The exact details depend on the company's holiday schedule. For example, some businesses in the US make the Christmas or new years breaks a bit longer than the holiday itself.

In addition, many employees take vacations at this time of year, so the company may be working a bit slower than usual.

So right now, I wouldn't be surprised to see "3 business days" mean a full week on the calendar.

Comment: Thanks. No idea about other part of my question?

Comment: Haven't used that service; no opinion.